# MarkerOnClickListener is not working

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am trying to set MarkerOnClickListener to start an Intent Activity after click
but it doesn't work.

```
  mapFragment.getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent (MapFeedsFragment.this,SingleView.class);
                            intent.putExtra("userId",post.getUserId());

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: startActivity(intent); You need to call this after intent.putExtra to open the new activity.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `startActivity(intent)`.

Answer (score 2):

To start activity you must call `startActivity()` which you are not doing.

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MapFeedsFragment.this,SingleView.class);
intent.putExtra("userId",post.getUserId());
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `startActivity(intent);` before `return true;`